# Multiple includes with #include in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, include

I have a question regarding the `#include` preprocessor directive in C++.

In my program I would like to include a header file from another directory. For this I have used the full path, example:

```
#include "full/path/to/my/header.hpp"
```

Now it turns out that `header.hpp` itself has an include (let's say `#include "otherheader.hpp"`. During compilation, the compiler complains that it cannot find this other header.

What is the best way to handle this problem, considering the fact that I also don't want to write the full path for every header file, especially including those that are only needed "further down the tree"?

Comment: Most C++ compilers accept some `-I`  option. Read the documentation of your compiler (e.g.  [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html))

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should use your compiler's `-I` option.**

Example with `g++`:

```
g++ -I full/path/to/my/
```

Then in your code you can simply put:

```
#include "header.hpp"
```

[More information on search path.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Comment: If you use -I , its better to use `#include <header.hpp>` for readability purpose

Comment: @RonanBoiteau <> suggest that predefined path is used first, "" suggests that local file is used first. While both will find proper file if name is unique, it is considered a good style to write this way. Imagine that another header.hpp was added to same folder as source file, then "" variant would include incorrect header

Comment: @Swift What if you have a header with the same name in your system headers? Does <> check the `-I` path(s) first?

Comment: @RonanBoiteau Formally that's an UB in this case, implementation-defined - you can't use names of standard or system headers, nkr you never should use identifiers existing in C/C++ standard headers or any reserved by standard. Depends on your compiler, though I think g++ prefers -I.

Answer (score 4):

Most compilers allow you to specify the root for additional include directories when compiling. For example, in Visual C++ you specify the `-I` flag. It's also the same for gcc. For example:

```
compiler -Ipath/to/headers myfile.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify full path to includes. Specify include directories to the compiler instead and then just `#include <foo>` knowing that `foo` will be found in `/some/path/foo` because you told the compiler to search `/some/path/` for includes. For many compilers this is done with the `-I` option.